# Dynamic trigger creation from managed package

Tags: apex, trigger, managed-package

I have a requirement to create triggers dynamically after a managed package is installed. I have read that the tooling API can be used to create triggers dynamically however it cannot be used in production. Is it possible to create triggers from a managed package in an org? I want to be able to create the trigger based on some user inputs.

Comment: Why do you think you can't use the Tooling API in production?

Comment: can't you add your triggers to managed package? Or write triggers in a sandbox with this package installed and then deploy them to prod?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new trigger? Can't you have a trigger as part of the package and let the user inputs be saved as custom settings?

Comment: @martin it is not always true that trigger should be on the object, which is part of managed package.
gerad26 -- you can use tooling api, as Adrian Larson said

Comment: [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) does this on a configuration page (visualforce). It's open source, so you can take a peek under the hood.

Comment: @Novarg,martin - I need the trigger to access some custom objects which are created by the user. So I do not know in advance what the inputs to the trigger would be. For eg, when a lead gets updated/created , I want to be able to add a field to it which is a custom object id created previously by the user

Comment: @Adrian- read some previous answers - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87695/tooling-api-in-managed-packages-salesforce. Apologies I guess I can use the metadata api instead as mentioned

Comment: @sfdcfox - thanks for the link. I had looked at that but it seemed too complex for my requirement and am not sure how it would act on the governer limits and other SF requirements. Was wondering if there was a simpler approach that could be hooked up with the visualforce page. Guess should read up on the DLRS a bit more.

Comment: @gerad26 It is complicated, but that's because we don't have simple [metadata services in Apex Code](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4TkAAI), and we don't have [ZIP files in Apex Code](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007RhvAAE). It's theoretically possible to use the [SOAP-based Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_calls_intro.htm), but that's non-trivial as well (but not impossible). There are ways to do what you want.

Comment: @sfdcfox I see. Would you recommend looking at the metadata API or exploring DLRS to find what they are doing under the hood? I have no experience in either, so can take any approach

Comment: @gerad26 I am not sfdcfox, but couple months earlier I have used DLRS approach for some managed package. It is not that complex, so you can use it either. That would be also good for generic sfdc knowledge:)

Comment: @gerad26 DLRS already has all the moving parts you need, it's just a matter of putting them into the desired order. Also, see Andrew's other projects; he's also written a generic metadata API thing you can try out.

Comment: @gerad26 [Found the link](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) for that other metadata API thing I was talking about.

Comment: @all, thanks so much. DLRS seems like a better approach. Would explore more in that direction.

Comment: @gerad26 Did you manage to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible via the SOAP API (in Enterprise production systems the Tooling API will indeed not work. It does in Dev Hub orgs and dev orgs, which makes things pretty confusing). You'll need a zip library to zip up the triggers, then create a package.xml file with ApexTrigger and (assuming you have test classes for your triggers) ApexClass Sections.

Due to the requirement to zip the files, we do that part in Javascript, using jszip, adding "files" (the strings making up the triggers and classes) with code like this:

```
            zipFile.file('triggers/'+triggerName+'.trigger',buildTrigger(triggerName,objectName));
            zipFile.file('classes/'+className+'.cls',buildClass(className,objectName));
```

To actually deploy the file, we are not using Javascript but rather the MetadataAPI surfaced by the Metadataservice class, generated from the SOAP API with wsdl2apex using this code:

```
    /* create triggers and classes with zipped metadata */
public static String createNewMetadata(String zipData,List<String> allTestClasses) {
     // Deploy zip file           
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataService.createService();
    MetadataService.DeployOptions deployOptions = new MetadataService.DeployOptions();
    deployOptions.allowMissingFiles = false;
    deployOptions.autoUpdatePackage = false;
    deployOptions.checkOnly = false;
    deployOptions.ignoreWarnings = false;
    deployOptions.performRetrieve = false;
    deployOptions.purgeOnDelete = false;
    deployOptions.rollbackOnError = true;
    deployOptions.testLevel = 'RunSpecifiedTests';
    deployOptions.runTests = allTestClasses;
    deployOptions.singlePackage = true;

    // if its not test code deploy, otherwise return a fake ID
    if (!Test.isRunningTest())  {
        MetadataService.AsyncResult asyncResult = service.deploy(zipData,deployOptions);  
        return asyncResult.id;
    }
    else {
        return '123';
    }

}
```

Comment: Very helpful example. Thanks for sharing!