# Create Dynamic Trigger from Managed Package

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata-api, apexrest, dynamic-apex

I want to create a trigger based on user's input after they install my managed package. Can anybody please explain in detail on what are the possible solutions for this?

I did look at one solution:
[Dynamic trigger creation from managed package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155868/dynamic-trigger-creation-from-managed-package/271472) but I need more detailed insight on this one or any other solution, if anybody can provide, please.

Thank you!

Comment: As per comments on that cited Q&A, if you really want detail you can get [open source code](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) that includes doing this...

Comment: Did you manage to do it ?